# Possible to display current time in pi camera recording?

Tags: python, camera, real-time

Well I guess the title sums it up pretty good. I know I can do annotations but they're just strings which can't be altered or am I wrong? Is it possible to always have the time in the video recording? I'm trying this with python if this is possible I would appreciate a little hint

Clarification: I want to overlay the current time of the day (year/month/day /hours/minutes/seconds) not the runtime of the video

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify whether you'd like to overlay the current time of day, or the current run-time of the video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [picamera documentation page](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html) includes a basic recipe for a timestamp overlay, which I've just tested, which puts a second-accurate timestamp (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) at the top of the video.

```
import picamera
import datetime as dt

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
    camera.framerate = 24
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.annotate_background = picamera.Color('black')
    camera.annotate_text = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    camera.start_recording('timestamped.h264')
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    while (dt.datetime.now() - start).seconds < 30:
        camera.annotate_text = dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        camera.wait_recording(0.2)
    camera.stop_recording()
```

Comment: In answer to @goobering
The issue with this solution, is that each time you need to stop&start the camera, which can be problematic in the solutions where you use split_recording. For example when you create security camera, than you cannot use stop&start many time as that will cut the videos.

Comment: do you have any idea/solution to this issue?

Comment: In response to haykp, where do you see the camera starting and stopping? It is only starting once, and stopping once. It is [waiting (see here)](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html?highlight=wait_recording#picamera.camera.PiCamera.wait_recording) frequently, but this does not cause the recording to stop. `wait_recording` also accepts a `splitter_port` argument, to handle split recordings.